# Declaring an array of objects, why do i not need to apply new inside the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

**-------------------Question 1:------------------------**

I have a Scene class and I want to make an array of scenes called... well... "scenes":

```
class Scene
{
public:
    int id;
    string title;
    Image backgroundImage;
    Scene( int id, string title, Image backgroundImage );
};
```

I declare the scenes array inside my Game class in a game header:

```
Scene scenes[ 2 ];
```

I then start pumping it with scenes inside my game.cpp loop de loop:

```
scenes[ 0 ] = Scene();
```

How comes I can do the above without having to declare a new Scene? for example:

```
scenes[ 0 ] = new Scene();
```

Is it because I did not declare the class Scene as public? does it get created as a static or something? I'm confused Scooby!

**--------------------Question 2-----------------------**

Is there a better way of passing properties for the scene through to the constructor... For example in javascript you might do this:

```
var Scene = function( properties )
{
    this.id = properties.id;
    this.string = properties.string;
    this.backgroundImage = properties.backgroundImage;
}

var scenes = [
    new Scene( { 
        id:0, 
        string:"a scene", 
        Image: new Image( ... ) 
    } ),        
    new Scene( { 
        id:1, 
        string:"a scene 1", 
        Image: new Image( ... ) 
    } ),
]
```

this then becomes self documenting.. d'ya catch my drift brah?

**------------Note------------:**

I think you have to declare it as new because I did not know that just saying scenes[ 0 ] = Scene() declares a new instance of the object?

Comment: Go to the blackboard and write 100 times: "C++ is not Javascript".

Comment: The question is, why do you think you would have to write `new Scene()` in the first place?

Comment: javascript is not Java.. but you are forgiven... lol, no that's fine.. was just making sure I had to pass them in as parameters to the constructor.. no problem mr robotto. hah!

Comment: Now as @juanchopanza stated, why do I not have to declare as new?

Comment: What you've presented here won't compile either with or without `new`. State your question clearly and post short, self contained, correct (compilable) example.

Comment: I didn't state that. I asked why did you think you *would* have to write `new`. C++ isn't one of the languages where you have to write `new` to instantiate an object.

Comment: @JamesT - forgiven for what? `<g>` (yes, I edited my comment...)

Comment: Hm, while the discussion rages, let me mention my once confusion between "Outlook" and "Outlook Express". Two very different products from Microsoft, perhaps intentionally with confusing names. Probably for the same reason that Sun chose to call their scripting language "JavaScript" (to confuse with their Java). But *then* we're onto why Bjarne called his language "C++"... <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:

```
Scene scenes[ 2 ]; /declares an array of Scene objects
scenes[ 0 ] = Scene();
How comes I can do the above without having to declare a new Scene? for example:

scenes[ 0 ] = new Scene();
Is it because I did not declare the class Scene as public?
```

`new` operator creates an object, returns a `pointer` to the object of class. If you use `new`, you need to declare the array as an array of pointers to `Scene`. In your array of objects case, if you do not specify which constructor to call to initialize those objects, it will call the default constructor.

Comment: This is the answer because he answered the question, but the other answers are absolutely rad too, cheers brahs!

Answer (score 1):

```
Scene scenes[2];
```

This creates an array of 2 `Scene` objects. Not pointers to objects. Objects. Each object is initialized with the default constructor.

To create an array with objects initialized by some other constructor, just do it:

```
Scene scenes[2] = {
  Scene(0, "a scene", Image(...)),
  Scene(1, "a scene 1, Image(...)) };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Image {};

class Scene
{
private:
    int id_;
    string title_;
    Image backgroundImage_;
public:
    Scene( int id, string const& title, Image const& backgroundImage )
        : id_( id )
        , title_( title )
        , backgroundImage_( backgroundImage )
    {}
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Scene scenes[] = {
        Scene( 0, "a scene", Image()  ),
        Scene( 1, "a scene 1", Image()  )
        };
    // Whatever.
}
```

Comment: Instead of using id_(id) is there a way to make it know it should use the property passed in?

Comment: @JamesT: no, `id_(id)`, or assigning to `id_`, is basically the way to make it know. but you may generate id's automatically by incrementing a static counter. instead of letting client code select id.

Comment: That's a shame, you're making my code all messy_ :D, the id will be generated by some C#.NET site yoop yoop so hopefully will change that once I get past development of the model :D Cheers brah!

Answer (score 1):

1. In JavaScript, `new` creates an object, whereas in C++ it returns a pointer to that newly created object. So doing `scenes[0] = Scenes()` is correct.
2. Maybe you can try `std::vector`:

   ```
   #include <vector>

   std::vector<Scenes> scenes{
       Scenes{0, "a scene", Image{}},
       Scenes{1, "a scene1", Image{}},
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
class Scene
{
    int id;
    string title;
    Image backgroundImage;

public:
    Scene(int id, string const & title, Image const & backgroundImage)
    : id(id)
    , title(title)
    , backgroundImage(backgroundImage)
    { }
};

Scene scenes[2] = { Scene(1, "me", image1), Scene(2, "you", image2) };
```

With a modern compiler (C++11) you can also write:

```
Scene scenes[2] = { {1, "me", image1}, {2, "you", image2} };
```

And you would probably prefer `std::array<Scene, 2>`.

Comment: I assume Visual Studio 2010 - 2012 will cater for this.. I love the way you can do that! But I also love "Cheers and hth. - Alf"'s way!